# calendar doesn't display on toolbar

Tags: 13.10, calendar

I noticed the Calendar has vanished from the toolbar. I remember seeing it but today I can't see it.

Is it related to *2013-2014 transition*? How do I get it back? I have a Win 8.1/Ubuntu 13.10 dual boot Dell Inspiron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not related to year transition.Try the below command on terminal to install date and time indicator,

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

After that logout and login back to take effect.

Comment: Thank you! that solved the issue. Can you tell me what the issue was? when I tried the above command, it told me nothing was installed/upgraded. But after logoff-logon I see the time calendar

Comment: usually after installation of indicators,unity,compiz we need to logout and login back to take effect,otherwise it doesn't.